# Blank UIActivityViewController swift 5

Tags: swift, pdf, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to share a PDF file that i created with PDFKIT. This pdf file is stored in `myVariables` struct. Here is the code that i use to display the ActivityView when a button is pressed.

```
@IBAction func shareButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let shareContent = [myVariables.pdfInView]
    let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareContent,
                                                      applicationActivities: nil)
    self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

However, when i run my code, i just get completely blank UIActivityViewController with nothing.

Comment: What does `myVariables.pdfInView` store? The PDF `Data`? I know passing the file path to the pdf works. Maybe try that.

Answer (score 1):

You get completely blank UIActivityViewController with nothing just because your **shareContent** is nil.Please check that for example use below code:

```
let shareContent = ["Example"]
```

[image: After using this code you will get result like this]

Hope it will help you.Thank you.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response but when i print my shareContent i get this [Optional(<PDFDocument: 0x6000021b8280>)]. So i feel like it is not nil.